# How do I work out my altitude without knowing the barometric pressure at sea level?

Tags: pressure

I am trying to work out what altitude I am currently at without knowing the sea level barometric pressure, only the barometric pressure that I am currently at, which is constantly changing. I ca use any data that is available at my current altitude. I was trying to work out the current sea level pressure by using my current pressure level, but that requires knowing the altitude, which requires knowing the current sea level pressure. It's kind of using one thing to work out another, but it needs that other data to work out that first thing.
Does anyone know the answer to this convoluted question?
This is to make a BME680 do "machine learning" of a sort. I can change it to code if I know the formula on how to work this out.

Comment: Did you tried [pressure-altitude law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_altitude) ?

Comment: By principle, you simply cannot. You need a reference point somewhere. The formula at the above commenter's page clearly states that the "altitude" it produces is altitude above an imaginary line at a certain pressure. If you use that as your altitude above sea level then you're making the assumption the pressure at sea level is whatever is in the formula (which may or may not be reasonable). I.e. you're letting the formula "guess" the pressure at sea level for you. Have you considered getting a reference point with GPS?

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have a good weather map, it gives you the pressure at sea level in your region.
2. if you have no information of pressure and hight at any point there is no formula to calculate you hight .
3. to see why 2. think about your income. It changes over time, but without knowing the income of Mr X you will not know how much higher your income is than his.